# What is a typical example of taylor series for $f(z)$ that converges iff $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

What is a typical example of taylor series for $f(z)$ that converges iff $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ where $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ is not a natural boundary ?

Comment: What? No Taylor series converges iff Re(z)>0

Comment: The region of convergence of a power series (in one variable) is _always_ a disk.

Comment: Im sorry guys , but I believe a Taylor series can converge outside its radius NOT ?

Comment: Im sorry Daniel Fisher is right. That seems to answer the question. Proof is not hard.